# How do I order mysql query results by values from a joined table's rows (not columns)?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table `items` and a table `parameters`. A join table of `item_parameters` stores the value for each possible parameter for an item, instead of having a separate column for each parameter.

For example (simplified):

```
parameters:             items:              
id: 1, name: color      id: 1, name: bike
id: 2, name: size       id: 2, name: phone
id: 3, name: weight     id: 3, name: shoe

item_parameters: 
id: 1, item_id: 1, parameter_id: 1, value: "blue"
id: 2, item_id: 1, parameter_id: 2, value: "large"
id: 3, item_id: 1, parameter_id: 3, value: "heavy"
id: 4, item_id: 2, parameter_id: 1, value: "black"
id: 5, item_id: 2, parameter_id: 2, value: "medium"
id: 6, item_id: 2, parameter_id: 3, value: "medium"
id: 7, item_id: 3, parameter_id: 1, value: "white"
id: 8, item_id: 3, parameter_id: 2, value: "small"
id: 9, item_id: 3, parameter_id: 3, value: "light"
```

How can I search for items (applying a filter for specific parameters) and order the results based on the `value` of a particular `parameter` for the `items`?

I know how to apply the filter part, using a where clause with `item_parameters.parameter_id = ? AND item_parameters.value = ?` But for the ordering part, simply adding `ORDER BY item_parameters.value desc` doesn't seem to be enough to order by only those `item_parameters.value` `where item_parameters.parameter_id = ?`.

In my results of items, I want all `item_parameters` for that `item` including the `parameters` that weren't used in the order by clause.

This query is still a work in progress because I don't yet have it returning all `item_parameters` for each `item`:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
         `items`.name,
         `parameters`.name,
         `item_parameters`.value
 FROM `items` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `item_parameters` ON `item_parameters`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `parameters` ON `item_parameters`.`parameter_id` = `parameters`.`id`
 WHERE (item_parameters.parameter_id = 3 AND item_parameters.value = 'light') 
 ORDER BY item_parameters.value LIMIT 10000;
```

In addition currently not returning all item_parameters, the relevant missing piece above for this post is that the order logic (pseudocode) needs to be `ORDER BY items_parameters.value where item_parameters.parameter_id = 1`

Here is an example of desired results, assumes from a larger example data set than the provided example above:

```
item name     color       size      weight
cup           brown       small     light
shirt         green       medium    light
candy         pink        large     light
chair         tan         medium    light
paper         white       large     light
```

Notice that the results are all filtered on parameter 3 (weight) = light and ordered on parameter 1 (color).

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Comment: can you show use the statement your are currently using?

Comment: Philipp, I added my query (current state) to the post. As I stated in the post, I haven't yet gotten it to the point where it is returning all `item_parameters` for each `item`.

Comment: Is it correct that you want all parameters for items that have parameter 39's value as 'seamless'? Also what order do you want these in? An example of expected results would be invaluable.. also your example query doesn't match up with your example data.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is making your LEFT OUTER JOIN behave as an INNER JOIN. If you want to return the records whether they match or not, but only the item_parameter details if they do match then move the checks in the WHERE clause into the ON clause instead.

Comment: Arth, I updated the example query to match more closely to the example data and I added an example results set (that would obviously come from a larger data set than I've added in the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's best for performance but here's how I would logically construct the query.

First SELECT all the items and their parameters:

```
   SELECT i.name, p.name, ip.value
     FROM items i
     JOIN item_parameters ip
       ON ip.item_id = i.id
     JOIN parameters p
       ON p.id = ip.parameter_id
```

Then make sure you only have items that have the correct value for a particular param:

```
     JOIN item_parameters ip3
       ON ip3.parameter_id = 3
      AND ip3.item_id = i.id
      AND ip3.value = 'light'
```

Then include the param that you are ordering by:

```
     JOIN item_parameters ip1
       ON ip1.parameter_id = 1
      AND ip1.item_id = i.id
```

Then add the ORDER BY:

```
 ORDER BY ip1.value DESC, i.id, p.id
```

If you are ordering by a parameter that may not be present, you'll have to LEFT JOIN to that one and choose where to put the resultant NULL values.

This also will NOT pivot the table as shown in your example results, but will keep the items grouped together nicely.

If you wish to have the pivoted table, you'll probably have to join all the parameters separately, similar to 1 and 3 above. You can either do this manually or by dynamically building the query from a list of expected/required parameters.

**UPDATE**

For the pivoted results shown, with a bit of hard coding:

```
  SELECT i.name, color.value color, size.value size, weight.value weight
    FROM items i
    JOIN item_parameters color
      ON color.parameter_id = 1
     AND color.item_id = i.id
    JOIN item_parameters size
      ON size.parameter_id = 2
     AND size.item_id = i.id
    JOIN item_parameters weight
      ON weight.parameter_id = 3
     AND weight.item_id = i.id
   WHERE weight.value = 'light'
ORDER BY color.value DESC
```

You could join on the parameters table to get the names too just in case they change, but this gives you an outline.

The downside of this approach is that the query will have to be updated every time you add a new parameter.

Personally, I prefer the group style method, the pivot table can be generated using application code.

Comment: Excellent Arth! I ran a test on my actual dataset and based on my initial review it appears to be working as expected, with the exception like you say that the data is grouped but not pivoted. When you say I would have to join the parameters separately to have the pivot table, what else is required besides just joining them to do the pivot? If you assume I only have those 3 parameters, what would the rest of the query need to be to transpose the results into columns (pivoted)? I will mark your post as the answer but would it be much more to show the extra portion to get the pivoted table? Thx!

Comment: Thanks!.That works perfectly now. I can dynamically build the query up at the ruby level so its no problem that parameters will change. The list of the parameters is dynamically generated based on the category selected. So, this query with your help now returns a dynamically generated table of columns based on selected category, without needing to define different tables of parameters for each category. What sort of performance issues, if any, would you anticipate with this approach vs a giant item_parameters table with pre-defined columns for all possible parameters across all categories?

Comment: I think you'll get better perfomance/more portable code if you stick to this approach but with my first method.. as there are less joins, you can easily build the table itself in the app code. The giant table may be faster, but is very inflexible, and a mass of indexes could slow it down a lot. If the params are never going to change this may be the fastest option.